# Front-end Syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, php

Whats the best way to get front end syntax highlighting like this page?

http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/enable-milestone-sales-alerts-easy-digital-downloads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did some digging into the page, and found out that the page uses `google-code-prettify`

You can find the link [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-code-prettify/)

Haven't used it personally, but it's a starting point for you.